# Excel INDEX() function with array constants vs. ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

The answers to [this Excel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998632/is-there-any-documentation-of-the-behavior-of-built-in-excel-functions-called-wi) and links to other pages were very helpful understanding arrays in Excel.

I played around with it for a while and did not detect a general rule that covered all the situations. I continue to be a little puzzled about the behavior of the `INDEX()` function.

[Here is a workbook](https://ln.sync.com/dl/a3c001fa0#waxftqja-xg9qvhw4-5x8dv7mx-rfd8ttph) that demonstrates some of the things I discovered. They mostly have to do with "edge cases" like a one-dimensional array or range when using the row and/or column arguments. If the notes in the workbook are not clear, please comment here.

Question: If someone else could come up with a general explanation of why `INDEX()` behaves as it does, that would be great, especially if it also generalized to other array formulas and functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example sheet is very thorough.

N/A Errors:
When you use array functions (what Excel calls functions spread over a cell range and in the curly braces { .. } ) and the function returns a smaller grid of results than the range the function is asked to fill through the array function , it puts #N/A for Not Available Error in the surplus cells.

REF Errors:
When the supplied range to the INDEX(..) function is too small for the row and column index arguments you get a #REF error. The #REF error is Excel's way of telling you that it can not find the cell you are trying to reference. #REF is short for Reference Error

TRANSPOSE Issue:
You have REF errors in Column D because you have asked for the third column's value (_x3) in a 5x1 shaped range  (the transpose of the 1x5 shaped range at A48:E48 is 5x1 shaped). Likewise Column C returns the value 5. 
Rows 54 and 56 have the same underlying issue.

Comment: I think my workbook was a little unclear about which things I was questioning. I knew that my array bounds were larger than the arrays in some cases, and I understand most of the N/A and REF errors. I'll update the sheet tomorrow to clarify what I'm asking about. Mostly, I don't understand the flakiness of `INDEX()` in its use of the row and column arguments. Just one example: you mentioned Column D in my example, and Column D shows what I expected, but why does Row C above that **not** also have REF errors? (See the note to the left of Row C).

Comment: In Column D you skip an argument putting the 3 in the 'col' position =INDEX(TRANSPOSE(A48:E48),,3) by omitting the row argument you invoke INDEX in it's array mode and get all the rows at column three, but you only have one so it repeats. In Column C you have =INDEX(TRANSPOSE(A48:E48),3) fixing the value for the 'row' and allowing =INDEX() to default the 'col' value in array mode, but col 3 does not exist at all.

Comment: Sorry I did not have time to update the workbook today. Regarding your comment on Columns C and D, those behaved as I expected. My puzzlement had to do with Rows C and D in the grid above the column examples. I expected Row C to show #REF! errors the same way Column D did, but it didn't. I discovered that `=INDEX(A48:E48,3,)` (note trailing comma) does cause the #REF! error. (Also note that all the formulas were entered as array formulas with CSE.)  I'm keeping notes on all this and hope I can come up with a comprehensive description of how this function works.

Comment: I applaud your efforts to document the INDEX function however there is no standard necessarily enforced between Excel functions. They can and probably do treat these edge cases differently. I know from experience writing Excel functions using their C /xll API that it is left up to the programmer's judgement what to do.

Comment: I'm glad to hear about your experience. I have not used an Excel API, so it helps to know that. I will continue to explore the `INDEX ()` function so I can become more comfortable with it. Thanks!